# Largest Number from leetcode : can someone explain why this method works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Here's [the question from leetcode](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/)

> Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they
>   form the largest number.
>
> For example, given [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], the largest formed number is
>   9534330.

Here's the simplest solution I've ever seen:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string largestNumber(vector<int> &num) {
        vector<string> arr;
        for(auto i:num)
            arr.push_back(to_string(i));
        sort(begin(arr), end(arr), [](string &s1, string &s2){ return s1+s2>s2+s1; });
        string res;
        for(auto s:arr)
            res+=s;
        while(res[0]=='0' && res.length()>1)
            res.erase(0,1);
        return  res;
    }
};
```

I am so confused that why this method works..Could anybody give a prove to this method?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that every number you form with all the elements of the vector has the same number of digits. That's why we can use lexicographical sorting on strings.

So what we could do in a naive way is to list all posibile concatenations and select the largest from it.

The string comparison used for sorting makes use of the above noted fact for the special case of 2 elements in the vector. So we could modify the naive implementation to first search for the largest to elements using this comparator, concatenate them and then repeat with a vector whose size has been decreased by 1 (the newly concatenated element is also contained in the new vector). But then again, we would choose that newly concatenated element and the remaining largest element for going on. if we would not choose that newly concatenated element, than we wouldn't have picked the 2 largest elements of the vector in the first place. So we pick out the elements one by one in decreasing order. That's why the sort is applied first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take greates of all possible combinations of array members.
e.g. 3303459, 9534303, 9353430, 93534303, ....
so, at first you have to sort them, after combine in one string.
for sorting you can't just compare 3 with 30, you have to compare merged value of them 303 with 330, 
if you will check only members like 30 with 3, you'll have 303, but actually in this comparison you should have 330, because 330 > 303, that is why should compare `s1 + s2` with `s2 + s1`,

about while loop, possible suck test case [0, 0, 0, 0], for this case will be generated such string "0000", but it's not normal number, we have to remove all 0 started from left except last one, to get normal number "0"